# gson create ArrayList<Entity> from Map<String, String[]>

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, gson

I have entities with `atr1`, `atr2` and `atr3` or Entities with `atr4` and `atr5`.

And I want to create a method that from map type

```
Map1 key atr4 => String list of value1, value2 value3
     key atr5 => String list of value5, value6
```

and this interface:

```
private <T extends Object> T parameterToList(Class<T>  classOfT, Map<String,String[]> mapData)
```

get me a List (T will be a entity1 or entity2)

is it possible with gson?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution:

```
 public <T extends Object> List<T> parameterToList( Map<String,String[]> entity, Class<T> classOfT) {
    Map<String, String[]> collect = entity.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(p -> p.getKey().startsWith(entity))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey().replace(entity + ".", ""), p -> p.getValue()));

    JsonObject requestJson = new JsonObject();
    JsonArray main = new JsonArray();

    Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry1 = collect.entrySet().iterator().next();
    String key = entry1.getKey();
    int size = entry1.getValue().length;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : collect.entrySet()) {
            // add every item as a property to the json
            requestJson.addProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[i]);
        }
        i = i + 1 ;
        main.add(requestJson);
    } List<T> fromJson = gson.fromJson(main, new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType());

    return fromJson;
```